# Make a submit button

Tags: jquery

how will i make a submit button??

Comment: What do you mean? If you'd like the community to help you with an in-depth answer you should at least try to do your part. It's like getting to a company and saying: "Give me a job. Quick!"

Comment: This is not Twitter :)

Comment: "Do it!" "Do it NOW" - Arnold :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("<input type='submit' />").appendTo("form");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

Comment: He tagged the question as **jQuery**...

Comment: Yea, you HTML fanboy.... `:p`

Comment: Dammit, I could have sworn there were no tags when I submitted that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<p><input type="submit"></p>').appendTo('form:first');
```

Answer (score 0):

By learning HTML,

http://www.w3schools.com/

http://peepcode.com/

good luck! = D  haha

Answer (score 0):

Or in HTML5 you can do it this way:

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Question tag is **jQuery**... And BTW: you can use `button` element in HTML 4.01 as well. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

Comment: @Robert quite true, but I thought I'd add it in - just in-case it may be helpful. And yea, you could use that in HTML4 as well, but it wasn't encouraged (it was more standard to use input) - with HTML5 it's been redefined in a manner of speaking.